# PHP Laravel Instascan "not able to load script..."

Tags: laravel-5

at the moment i get in touch with laravel. i tried to create a page who scan qr codes.

i created a normal project with laravel (composer create-project laravel/laravel testqrinstascan) and tried to implement step by step instascan.

I wanna use this library instascan -> https://github.com/schmich/instascan

But i get everytime the error "Laden fehlgeschlagen für das  mit der Quelle "http://localhost:8000/instascan.min.js"."

but the file is in the same directory

It means loading script with source .... not possible -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9jRN.jpg

This is my welcome.blade.php------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="instascan.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        html, body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .full-height {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-center {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .position-ref {
            position: relative;
        }

        .top-right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 18px;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 84px;
        }

        .links > a {
            color: #636b6f;
            padding: 0 25px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: .1rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .m-b-md {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="links">
                <video id="preview"></video>
                Hello World

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview') });
                    scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
                        console.log(content);
                    });
                    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                        if (cameras.length > 0) {
                            scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                        } else {
                            console.error('No cameras found.');
                        }
                    }).catch(function (e) {
                        console.error(e);
                    });
                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can u specify the path where is ur instascan.min.js file?

Comment: app/resources/views/instascan.min.js with app/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

Comment: watch my repo for source code https://github.com/RahmanG/testQRinstascan

Comment: y u r not intrest to place ur js file in public folder?..i think it is best way to use javascript or css in laravel

Comment: place ur js file in public/js folder any use defined folder...link in welcome template like <script src="{{URL::to('/')}}/js/instascan.min.js"></script>..hope u try it..and best way to work

Comment: Thank you RamAnji i moved the file and it works!